# how to remove preference pane-based malware? (have already tried malware removal apps)

Tags: security, ventura, malware

Running macOS 13.4.1 or an i3 MacBook Air. At the top of Application Notifications I have had the following appear:

> ask you
>
> Confirm that you're not a robot, you need click Allow

If I allow it to, a message about my having virus, urging me to click on certain websites, appears.

I have tried to use malware removal apps. The malware does not even appear in the scan, therefore I can't remove. Strangely, it doesn't always appear. Earlier today it didn't. The MacBook has, in my subjective estimation, acted a little more unstable and glitchy over the last couple of months and I attribute this to the malware. What can I do?

Comment: That's not malware, it's just a scam website. Quit your web browser, then launch it again by clicking its icon while holding the Shift key. All "antivirus" software is useless, but that wasn't your question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the malware wants me to click on certain websites. Still, as I said, the text I quoted above appears under my notifications preferences, not in any browser.

I did do as you advised, but the text still remains.

Comment: Please post a screenshot.